# How do I fix weird resolution difference from nextjs 12 to 13?

Tags: typescript, next.js, resolution, screen-resolution

I have made a website with nextjs 12 in the past and wanted to upgrade the entire site from ground up to nextjs 13

I found a few weird problems one being that the index page works on my local build but it doesn't on vercel but that's not what this post is about.

I've added a bit of code to show me the current window reselution. As it was expected both my old website and my new website have the same reselution on a desktop which is 3072 x 1595 on a 4k screen which is close to native res
Usually tho, smartphones have a much lower resolution compared to the actual screen size. Now my problem I had is that my old website has a resolution of 412 x 811 while my new website has a resolution of 980 x 1929 which is more then double. Everything looks so small on a smartphone and is not usable at all. I dont know what I did on my older website if I even did anything. I thought it was automatic

Comment: Do you have the meta tag `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">` set on your page's `<head>`? See https://beta.nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/file-conventions/head for how to add tags to `<head>` in Next.js 13.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the same issue I had with this meta tag :

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
```

You can put this meta tag in `head.tsx` inside the app folder directory like this :

```
import React, { FC } from "react";

const Head: FC = () => {
  return (
    <>
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
      <title>NextJS 13 TailwindCSS</title>
    </>
  );
};

export default Head;
```

or use it in `layout.tsx` :

```
import React, { FC, ReactNode } from "react";
import { Footer, Header } from "../components";

interface LayoutProps {
  children: ReactNode;
}

import "./globals.css";
const Layout: FC<LayoutProps> = ({ children }) => {
  return (
    <html lang="en">
      <body>
        <header>
          <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
          <title>NextJS 13 TailwindCSS</title>
        </header>
        <main>{children}</main>
        <footer>
          <Footer />
        </footer>
      </body>
    </html>
  );
};

export default Layout;
```